# readdir() in php not seeming to work

Tags: php, http, archlinux

I'm working on the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$dir=opendir("docs/recipes");
$files=array();
while (($file=readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "index.php")
    {
        array_push($files, $file);
    }
}

closedir($dir);
sort($files,SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
print "<div class=\"blocktext\">";
foreach ($files as $file)
print "<A href=\"docs/recipes/$file\">$file</a><br>";

print "</div>";
?>
```

I had this working on my raspberry pi web server, but I moved my server to arch linux, and it doesn't seem to be working.  When I load the page, it spins but then the list of files is empty.

I have checked that httpd is running with systemd and because my webpages load.  I know php is working because my phpinfo test page works.

In the folder containing this file, I have a symbolic link called docs, and I know the path is correct.  I have all the files in the destination readable.  This file is executable.

Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Also, is there an easy way to troubleshoot php like this?  I'm pretty good at reading error messages, but since I never see any from php, that makes that kind of hard.

Comment: please check permission for the folder

Comment: All of the folders have the right permissions.  All owned by root and have read, write and execute permissions.  I know this is a bad habit, but I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a file permission error

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a solution, but some help with good practices and a way to find what is happening on your script

```
<?php
    // initialize variables first
    $dir = false;
    $files = array();

    // assign the handler
    $dir = opendir( "docs/recipes" );

    // work only if necessary
    if ( $dir !== false ) {
        while ( ( $file = readdir( $dir ) ) !== false )     {
            if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "index.php") {
                array_push($files, $file);
            }
        }
        closedir( $dir );
        sort( $files,SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE );
        print "<div class=\"blocktext\">";
        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            print "<A href=\"docs/recipes/$file\">$file</a><br>";
        }
        print "</div>";
    } else {
        // get informed that something is wrong, print anything that helps you
        echo( 'problems opening' );
        exit( __FILE__.' '.__LINE__ );
    }
?>
```

Comment: So I tried this, and it went in to the else statement.  I tried using an absolute path rather than the symbolic link "docs" and that failed as well.  However, I moved the folder into /srv/http and that worked just fine.  Is there a problem with linking to files outside of the http directory?  It worked just fine this way in raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

from php.net/readdir comes a warning: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

you have not specified which version of PHP you are using, nor if it's installed/compiled locally. it would help. my guess is that you don't have all errors turned on, and readdir is catching one of those corner cases.

try this:

```
  $cycle = true;
  while ( $cycle !== false ) {
    $file = readdir( $dir );
     print ( "GOT a FILe or a FALSE:". $file ."br>" );
    // do your stuff here
    $cycle = $file;
  }
```

then in php.ini set the errors to E_ALL. if using PHP >= 5.4 (i guess you are, since you're on arch  :) you can fire up the built-in server, so all errors/logs/messages go straight to STDERR. just do a command from the folder where your index.php is located:

```
 $ php -S <local ip>:<some port>
```

open as usual in the browser (or a curl, or whatever). output goes to browser, errors go  straight to console, no middle-man to cover up any message.

this should enable you to catch the real problem. and/or, you can wrap it all up in a try-catch and see if something pops up.